# Detecting a crawl (Search Engine's visit) using PHP

Tags: php, seo, search-engine, user-agent

When a search engine visits a webpage, what does `get_browser()` function and `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`  return?

Also, what is the other possible evidence that PHP offers when a search engine crawls a webpage?

Comment: Why does it matter? If you serve them different content you're violating their TOS and risk being banned.

Comment: @JohnConde, Not going to apply it... just curious...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php

Comment: Before the question gets closed as exact duplicate, can any one tell me what `get_browser()` returns?

Comment: @TabrezAhmed - At the end of the day it is electical impulses into you machine. I am/have/will fake being an IE browser along with the others. You will not be able to tell the difference. Web crawlers can be curtious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function *attempts to determine* the browser's features (in array) but dont count too much on it because of the `non standard user-agents`; instead, for a serious app, build your own.
- the `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` is a long string "describing" the user's browser and can be used as first parameter in the above function (optional); **A tip**: use this one to uncover user's browser instead of get_browser() itself! Also be prepared for a *missing* user agent as well! An example of this string is this:
  **Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/418 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/417.9.3**
- a search engine or robot or spider or crawler that [follows the rules](http://www.cs.washington.edu/lab/policies/draft/crawlers.html) will visit your page according to the information stored of **robots.txt** that must exist in your site's root.
  Without a robots.txt a *spider can crawl the whole site*, as long as it find **links** inside your pages; if you have this file you can program it so to tell the spider **what** to search; **NOTE:** this rule applies only to "good" spiders and not the [bad ones](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Bad_RDF_Crawlers)

Comment: `robots.txt` is just a hint, along with sitemaps.

Answer (score 1):

`get_browser()` & `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will return you the `Useragents`, it should look like this :

Google :

- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117 Safari/6531.22.7 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
- Googlebot-Image/1.0

Bing :

- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b
- msnbot/2.0b (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)
- msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)

Yahoo :

- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)

-> To fully control (and limit) the crawl don't use **robots.txt**, use **.htaccess** or **http.conf** rules. (good crawler don't give a f*** about your disallow rules half of the time in robots.txt)