# AB Testing in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ab-testing

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter for AB Testing, but this is a first for me, so please forgive the newbie question.

I have found that in index.php I can control which applications folder to present to a user based on the following:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['subsite']))
{
        $application_folder = "application".$_SESSION['subsite'];
}
elseif(rand(1,2) % 2)
{
        $application_folder = "application";
        $_SESSION['subsite'] = '';
}
else
{
        $application_folder = "application_old";
        $_SESSION['subsite'] = '_old';
}
```

However, this will redirect all traffic without any indication of a redirect. I am concerned that SEO can take a dive with this method as Google and other bots will be continually seeing different versions of the site. Can someone please provide the appropriate procedure for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user agent string to determine if a visitor is a search engine crawler.

User agent string is stored in $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in PHP.  You can check out this SO post for more information: [how to detect search engine bots with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php)