# How to check if the request is from google, facebook, twitter and bing crawlers?

Tags: php, laravel, web, handlebars.js, template-engine

I want to serve a web application and Compile a template in JavaScript with tow-way data binding.
on the other hand , I want to produce just ready HTML content for web crawlers.

How to know if the request come from the popular web crawlers/bots such as Google,bing,facebook,twitter??

Comment: they usually tell you with the user agent. It'll say "google bot" or "Yahoo" or "bing" or something like that.

Comment: Why Didn't I Think of That

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php - That answers your question and includes a list of all search engines etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They usually send that kind of info through the user agent, something like

- Google crawler
- Yahoo
- Bing

Or something similar, in php you can find the user agent with

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

However, you should be aware that a user agent can be spoofed.