# Multilingual website and bot detection

Tags: php, node.js, web, seo, web-crawler

I have a website where I implement multilingual.

I divide my languages per subdomains.

```
fr-fr.mywebsite.com
es-es.mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com // root domain => neutral language for bots
```

On the subdomains, if a language cookie was not set, I use the subdomain as language code.

On the primary domain (www), if a language cookie was not set, then :

- if it's a bot, I use neutral language
- if it's not a bot, I detect the user language using the "accept-language" header.

How to detect safely if it is a robot? I read old topics on the matter but people simply used the "accept-language" because bots didn't send this header, however, to date, google sends this header...

Is it safer to detect if it's a bot, or inverse, to detect if it's a web browser?
Because if the bot is not detected, it's the website that will be indexed in wrong language.

Ideas ?

Comment: Why not use language annotations? in that way the bot will find the alternate languages pages

Comment: I use them too. But the primary domain have to auto detect user language :)

Comment: Hi @Ndrou, I still not understand why you need to find if the user is a bot, if the request has a valid "accept-language" header you can send it to the proper language site, and if not, to your main or default language site, if is a bot, he will be able to find all the altenate languages using the language annotations and index them too

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using PhP, you can request the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`and see if the user agent is 'googlebot'.

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
{
    // what to do
}
```

Here's the link to a question (and the example which I pulled from it).

[how to detect search engine bots with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php)

Comment: Yes, but there is not only googlebot, there are many bots as yahoo, bing, yandex, etc... How to be sure not to forget one ?

Comment: You can add in all those bots name, just google and look up the bot name. You can also add a log and just log the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` value and sort through the list to see if a bot-like name has popped up. All the well-known search engines and legitimate will name their bot.