# How can 1000 reported website visits result in all 1000 only visiting landing page, not any other sub page?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, ads, affiliate

How can Facebooks Ads Manager report I've got 1000 unique visitors, while Google Analytics reports that all these 1000 visits have just gone to the landing page (pdgeon.com/), and not any other sub page?

Now, you would think "the website is crap so every visitor decided to exit before visiting any other page on the website". But out of 1000 visitors, not ONE have decided to visit any other page than the landing page. My first thoughts are Facebook generates fake clicks or there are bots clicking the ad. I have indexed all pages so I know it would be reported if someone decided to go through to any other page.

Does anybody have any thoughts on why this happens?
I'm not buying the "this website is crap so 1000 visitors dont want to proceed browsing this website"-theory.

Comment: Most likely that’s their prefetch mechanism at work, that is preloading articles the user might want to click next on mobile. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049513/tracking-visitors-coming-from-facebook for more details.

Comment: I don't think that is the same issue. Facebook reports I've got 23000 unique exposures, and 1000 of them have made an outbound click. If the prefetch theory where the case, wouldn't all 23000 exposures be registered as outbound clicks on Analytics?