# Redirect users unless its a webcrawler

Tags: php, redirect, web-crawler

I want to prevent users from accessing the main page of my website since they have no reason whatsoever unless they authenticate through steam. So I set up a PHP script that redirects you to the login page if you are not signed in. And redirects you away from the login page if you are already signed in.

However this is giving me SEO issues as webcrawlers see a 302 redirect and don't do anything.

What php variable checks if its a webcrawler?

Comment: Why is your website set up in a way that the home page is not where users _want_ to go?

Comment: You can verify if the request is made by a web browser! @Halcyon, This behavior is common on systems. The truth is that the correct way is to define the login page, as the homepage, on this cases.

Comment: @Halcyon To prevent them from accessing the main site where they are unable to do anything unless logged in.

Comment: @nine consider putting a login form on the main page (or any page for that matter) if you're not logged in.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez you can't reliably detect spiders or bots. What if I used something like Selenium to access your website? I would consider that a bot but I doubt there is a way you could detect it.

Comment: @nine you can use is.js javascript library, to detect what browser is making the request, or even in what plattform.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez I can't use js because I'm using php to check whether or not the user is logged in, and using php to redirect them.

Comment: I'm probably going to go with the built in php variable that checks the user agent. Don't know if it'll work.

Comment: @nine, OK, look this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/677434/6107280