# Disable google indexing website telephone numbers

Tags: search, search-engine, google-index, search-engine-bots

I was presented with the task of hiding telephone numbers from Google - what that means is, we want to display them on the website and have them clickable `href="tel:..."` but to ensure Google does not index it and does NOT display it with the search results.

Does anyone know of any effective technique?
I was thinking of writing VueJs component, which mixes given number with some alpha characters, but this would only work with the presentation / label, the `tel:...` would still have to have a valid telephone number and I'm not sure if Google wouldn't pick it form the `href` attribute.

Comment: I think the best approach is just to hide it from bots, may be you can use something like this [VueIfBot](https://github.com/Developmint/vue-if-bot)

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I might give it a try - thanks very much.

Comment: I also found some notes on `googleoff` tags - will see if that will do anything as well.

Comment: good question - no particular reason - if it can work with other search engines then that's a bonus.

Comment: My point is that `googleoff` won't work on bing or any other search engine, if you want to protect your user phone number or something you need to check if the user is a bot. For example if i make my own crawler and i want to get all your users phone numbers what will stop me? Is that the case?

Comment: That's a valid point - client's brief was to hide it from google, but that's probably only because they use it as their main search engine. I've looked at that Vue package - I might take a few pieces of it and code my own as this one wraps the content in the `div` tag, which is not always desirable - especially with inline links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is just to hide it from bots, may be you can use something like this [VueIfBot](https://github.com/Developmint/vue-if-bot)

```
<vue-if-bot>
<a href="tel: ...">This will not be visible for bots</a>
</vue-if-bot>
```

or any other alternative just check the `userAgent` for example in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15047834/3768239)

```
function _bot_detected() {

  return (
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider|mediapartners/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
  );
}
```

If you can't get `userAgent`, but you still want to check if this is a search engine crawler you can check user IP adress here is a list of [IP Addresses of Search Engine Spiders](http://www.iplists.com/)

And finally after you successfully hide your data you can test it with [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf)