# Counting High Quality visitor for ads

Tags: javascript, php, ads

I Started to make a website that provide a shortlink with ads and then pay the publisher , but for advertiser they only want real people to see their persuasive ads , so my problem is how to know the viewer is real people and high quality enough to make the counter count them so i can give reward to the publisher ,

sorry if you don't understand my english is bad

THANKYOU VERY MUCH

Comment: There are some things you can do to improve these numbers, like filtering on user agent as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php), but depending on your level of experience on the field, my strong recommendation would be to outsource. While some bots openly admit to being bots and can easily be filtered on, others aren't that easy to distinguish without keeping track of problematic IP addresses et cetera, and instead of keeping track of that myself I would get a decent statistic tool to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some small REST API doing great IP verification **returning a score** for the IP you send, example :

```
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ; // your user IP
    
    $checkIp = file_get_contents('http://check.getipintel.net/check.php?ip='.$ip.'&contact=mail@example.com') ;
// don't forget to put a real e-mail
    
    if ($checkIp <=0.95) {
// this user is not a bot ! 
// do something here
    }
```

Then you can save the result in a session or a cookie so you don't have to call API on every page. I use to work with http://getipintel.net/ but based on the same idea you can use **google invisible captcha**.