# The best way for an App to recognize Bots (Googelbot/Yahoo Slurp)

Tags: post, cookies, get, googlebot

I have a (Rails) site and I *want* the search engines to crawl and index it. However, I also have some actions that I want to log as having happened - and these actions can be triggered by logged in users as well as users not logged in. Now, to ensure that the count for non-logged in ie anonymous users doesn't include bot traffic I am considering a few options and am looking for guidance on which way to go:

1. Set a cookie for all users, if this cookie doesn't come back since Bots usually dont accept or send back cookies, I can distinguish bots from anonymous humans.
2. Check the header and see if the agent is a bot (some whitelist): [How to recognize bots with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422969/how-to-recognize-bots-with-php)
3. Set that action to be a POST rather than a GET. Bots issue GETs so they don't get counted.
4. Any other approaches?

I am sure folks have had to do this before so what's the 'canonical' way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the spiders to follow the links, then you can use [`rel="nofollow"`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569) on them. However, since there might be other links pointing into the pages, you will probably also want to look at the User-Agent header. In my experience, the most common User-Agent headers are:

- Google: `Googlebot/2.1 ( http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)`
- Google Image: `Googlebot-Image/1.0 ( http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)`
- MSN Live: `msnbot-Products/1.0 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)`
- Yahoo: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp;)`

Comment: No problem — as you probably know, it's mostly used to prevent manipulating page rank when a site shows user-submitted external links, so your use case is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Just [check the `User-Agent` header](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Googlebot/), that might be enough for your purposes. Note that [a user agent can just pose as Google bot](http://www.thegooglecache.com/black-hat/googles-real-back-door/). So if you want to be sure more checking is needed. But I don't think you'd need to bother further than this.